# Get frequency data from audio file immediately using the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to get the frequency data of an audio file without having to play through the entire actual audio file. Right now I'm doing the following:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'testAudio.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);

var context = new AudioContext();
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

 var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
function renderFrame() {
   requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

   analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
}
renderFrame();
```

This works fine, but I need to wait for the entire audio file to play. Is there a way I can get this data immediately?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  You'll have to do your own FFT, via a library like [DSP.js](https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/).